# Calculating sin function with neural network using python

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, neural-network

I'm new in deep learning and trying to create a basic neural network for sin function. I have generated numpy array with random values of shape (50,1) which outputs `sin(input)`.

The neural network includes one Hidden layer (3 neurons) with activation function as `sigmoid` and final output neuron also consists `sigmoid` activation function. After training the network with epoch `20000` and learning rate as `0.1` **the final error does not seem to reach any close to zero**.

Full Code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import random
np.random.seed(1000)
input_array=np.random.uniform(size=(50,1))
output_array=np.sin(input_array)
total_rows=input_array.shape[0]

def sigmoid(x):
    d=(1/(1+np.exp(-x)))
    return d


def derivative_sigmoid(x):
    derivative=x*(1-x)
    return derivative


epoch=20000
hidden_layer=3
input_neurons=1
output_neurons=1
learning_rate=0.1
input_array=data['input'].values.reshape(total_rows,1)
output_array=data['output'].values.reshape(total_rows,1)    
weights_in=np.random.uniform(size=(input_neurons,hidden_layer)) 
bias_in=np.random.uniform(size=(1,hidden_layer))
weights_out=np.random.uniform(size=(hidden_layer,output_neurons))
bias_out=np.random.uniform(size=(1,output_neurons))

for i in range(epoch):

    #forward propogation

    hidden_layer_output=np.dot(input_array,weights_in)+bias_in
    activation_1=sigmoid(hidden_layer_output)
    activation_2_input=np.dot(activation_1,weights_out)+bias_out
    predicted_output=sigmoid(activation_2_input)


    # #backward propogation

    Error=(predicted_output-output_array)    
    rate_change_output=derivative_sigmoid(predicted_output)
    rate_change_hidden_output=derivative_sigmoid(activation_1)
    error_on_output=Error*rate_change_output
    error_hidden_layer=error_on_output.dot(weights_out.T)
    delta_hidden_layer=error_hidden_layer*rate_change_hidden_output
    weights_out+=activation_1.T.dot(error_on_output)*learning_rate
    weights_in+=input_array.T.dot(delta_hidden_layer)*learning_rate
    bias_out+=np.sum(error_on_output,axis=0,keepdims=True)*learning_rate
    bias_in+=np.sum(error_hidden_layer,axis=0,keepdims=True)*learning_rate
print (Error)
```

The reason I have used sigmoid functions as the final output is in range between 0-1 (Please correct me if I'm wrong). Here is the [error](https://www.dropbox.com/s/123190bopmtywzu/error.txt?dl=0).

Can anyone please suggest me what's possibly I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The values of sine move in the interval `[-1,1]`. If you use sigmoid as output activation your model can only output values in `[0,1]` and thus has no chance of predicting the values correctly.

Comment: That's Correct but based on my present output there is no negative values. So, neural network should be works fine.